# How to get the actual width and actual height for a control in WPF platform

Tags: wpf, textblock, measure, contentpresenter

I am preparing a custom control in the WPF platform in which I am using a content presenter for displaying a view and I am trying to display a text over the content presenter content using the text block control.
For the given text in the text block, I tried to calculate the actual width and actual height for the text block using the measure method for positioning the text block control, but it doesn't provide the actual width and height for the text block control. So that the text block control is not displaying in the view. The code snippet is provided below:
`this.CustomTextBlock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));`

Can anyone suggest to me how to calculate the actual width and actual height for controls in the WPF platform and also explain to me why the measuring method is not providing the actual width and actual height for the control in the WPF platform?

I have also attached the project download link below:[https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/BViewWpf1629602448][DemoProject]

Comment: whenever you try and measure control sizes in wpf it is very likly that your problem could be solved in a way easier way...why do you even want to get the size of your textbox? Why dont you just use dyamically rezising parents?
I am not saying that there is never a reason to measure a control, just saying i ve never come across a problem where this could not have been easily avoided and solved better with dynamic layouts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIElement.Measure` is a method that is executed by the framework's layout engine.
`Measure` is executed during the first layout pass and actually calculates the `DesiredSize`, which is used in the second layout pass when `Arrange` is invoked. `Arrange` may uses (depending on the implementation) `DesiredSize` to arrange its child elements. `Measure` has no direct influence on the actual size. It only calculates the maximum available space. The size passed into this method is not mandatory as it can be overridden by the measuring algorithm. The argument is considered to be minimum available space.

If you want to modify the size of a `FrameworkElement`, set the `Width` and `Height` properties.

To prevent the `TextBlock` from occupying the maximum available horizontal space, just set the `HorizontalAlignment` to something other than the default value `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`:

```
<!-- Use Padding to add additional space -->
<TextBlock Text="Minimum sized TextBlock" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Comment: Now I have set the text block width and height value from the desired value which is obtained from calling the measure method. The code snippet is provided below: `this.CustomTextBlock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); this.CustomTextBlock.Width = this.CustomTextBlock.DesiredSize.Width; this.CustomTextBlock.Height = this.CustomTextBlock.DesiredSize.Height;`.

Comment: My other goal is I will change the textblock text dynamically whenever I needed, So when I am updating the text I again call above code ie(calling the measure method) for calculating the desired size for the newly typed text. But in my case, it again returns the same desired size obtained for the previous text. So the new text is not displayed correctly. For example, if my initial text is "1" then if I update the text as "20" after loading the control, I am able to see only "2". Can you please tell why the measure method is not calculating the correct desired size after changing the text.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? The `TextBlock` will resize itself automatically to fit the text. Don't use `UIElement.Measure` for this.

Comment: _"Can you please tell why the measure method is not calculating the correct desired size after changing the text. "_: you explicitly set a width on the control which overrides the default value of  `Auto`. The control no  longer resizes automatically. You'd have to calculate the new length of the content on each input and resize accordingly. Again, don't do this. `TextBlock` has already an implementation that does the exact same thing. What you are doing doesn't make any sense. `Measure` is what the control internally executes to calculate rendering. You only need to set Width property.

Comment: Follow my example. I wrote everything in my answer.